# receiving an error error: use of undeclared identifier '__stl_hash_string' { return __stl_hash_string( __s.c_str() ); }

Tags: c++, macos, osx-mountain-lion, xcode4.6

I am receiving an error

```
error: use of undeclared identifier '__stl_hash_string'
                    { return __stl_hash_string( __s.c_str() ); }
```

while compiling using Xcode 4.6.1 on Mac OS 10.8.

/*------Code snippet below ----*/

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
    namespace __gnu_cxx
    {
            template<>
            struct hash<std::string>
            {
                    size_t operator()(const std::string& __s) const
                    { return __stl_hash_string( __s.c_str() ); } 
            };
    }
#endif
```

/*--------------------------------------*/
This code was working perfectly fine in Xcode 3.5 on Mac OSX 10.7 and 10.6.

I did a search for the `__stl_hash_string` method and found that its present in the folder 
`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ext/hash_fun.h`

However when I wrote a sample application to see if I can include this header it failed.

```
#include < cstddef >
#include < ext/hash_fun.h >
```

gave me error at the second line saying this header cannot be included. I am not sure whether this method is deprecated in the new environment, if its deprecated then what is the alternative method. I request your help in sorting out this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this function defined in libstdc++. This library was default in Xcode 3.5, now Xcode uses libc++ by default. But you can still switch it to libstdc++ in `C++ Standard Library` build setting.
But if you can use C++11 in your project I suggest you to use standard [std::hash](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/hash) function fo string and not rely on internal std functions.

Comment: Thanks for replying, Yes we are using libc++ 

CXX=clang++ CXXFLAGS='-stdlib=libc++'

Do you know the equivalent std::hash function for __stl_hash_string ??

Comment: May be you should try to add '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/' path to the Header Search Paths then?

Comment: Never mind, that answer was for your comment before you edited it.

Comment: Do you use C++11? If so you don't need any hand-made hash functions, they all already exist.

Answer (score 1):

Well I have modified my header file NOT to use this hash support definition when we use libc++

/

```
/ ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//      • hash function support
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#ifdef _LIBCPP_VERSION
        /*std::hash available in libc++ so no hash support required*/
#elif __cplusplus
        namespace __gnu_cxx
        {
                template<>
                struct hash<std::string>
                {
                        size_t operator()(const std::string& __s) const
                        { return __stl_hash_string( __s.c_str() ); }
                };
        }
#endif
```

Thanks cody for your answer. Now it compiles well. However adding '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/‌​SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ wont help coz this code is shared by many products. so cannot put absolute header paths.

Answer (score 1):

```
I have modified the code again so that there won't be any issues for any other clients using this header for the hash functionality.

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  • hash function support
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
#ifdef _LIBCPP_VERSION
    template<>
    struct hash<std::string>
    {
        size_t operator()(const std::string& __s) const
        {
            std::hash<std::string> hash_fn;
            return hash_fn(__s);
        }
    };
#elif __cplusplus

    namespace __gnu_cxx
    {
        template<>
        struct hash<std::string>
        {
            size_t operator()(const std::string& __s) const
            { return __stl_hash_string( __s.c_str() ); }
        };
    }
#endif
```